# Can't find variables with $http.post AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm having some trouble using $http.post() with angularJS.

When I use the "post" method with a form, I can find the data in my php file using $_POST, and it works fine.

But when I do, for example:

```js
$http.post(myUrl, {data: "test data"})
.success(function(){
  console.log("ok");
  });
```

How can I get the data and use it in my php file?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the PHP code that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Angular `$http` will use the header `Content-type: application/json` and send the request body as JSON.  You can get this in PHP using:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

[More information about `php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

If you don't want this and you want to use `$_POST` you will have to send the data as x-www-form-urlencoded which requires changing the header and sending the data as an `x-www-form-urlencoded` string.  For example:

```
$http({
  url: myUrl,
  data: "data=" + encodeURIComponent("test data"),
  method: "POST",
  headers: {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
});
```

If you want these settings to be global, you can configure them with `$httpProvider.defaults`